# Can I give different border width and borderColor to each bar in echarts.js bar graph

Tags: bar-chart, echarts

I was getting dynamic color for each bar in bargarph and tried to do the same for borderwidth and borderColor and , but is not working in the case of borderWidth or borderColor.
Here is piece of code

series: [{
itemStyle: {

```
       color: function (param:any) {
        return zoneColor[param.name] || '#5470c6';
      },
    
      borderWidth: function () {
        console.log("inside func")
        return zonewidth[param.name]|| 1;
      }
```

Comment: Would like to know an answer to this too .. how does one set a dynamic bordercolor .. neither specifying a function, or using a visualmap seems to work.